# How to remove the outermost border lines of table in flutter | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
                  Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 350,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Table(
                          defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(120.0),
                          border: TableBorder.all(
                            color: Colors.grey[600],
                            //style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 0.5,
                          ),
                          children: [
                            TableRow(),
                            TableRow(),
                            TableRow(),
                              ],
                              
                               ),
                          
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

I need to remove the outermost border line of this table. I here use Table widget to show the table. The image with this is the output i want. Is there any method to remove the outermost lines or any other ideas to make like this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v1BWmO56m6Zq4kPgiyOoCzv8K2XvrFU7/view?usp=sharing is the link of the widget i want to build.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/table-in-flutter-beyond-the-basics-8d31b022b451
This may help you to accomplish what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
child: Table(
    border: TableBorder(horizontalInside: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
```

This is how you can remove the border of the table in flutter.

Sample of the dart pad is attached below
https://dartpad.dev/0bc0f378c2722dc94e7a8c583180705e

For reading more about the article you can look ahead at
https://medium.com/flutter-community/table-in-flutter-beyond-the-basics-8d31b022b451

Answer (score 3):

In the [TableBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TableBorder-class.html) class there's a property `TableBorder.symmetric` which specifies the outer and inner border separately.

The optimized code would look like:

```
Table(
   border: TableBorder.symmetric(
       outside: BorderSide.none, 
       inside: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey, style: BorderStyle.solid),
   ),
   children: [
       TableRow(),
       TableRow(),
       TableRow(),
   ],
)
```